# Outlook 365 Web showing wrong count of contacts

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, office365, microsoft-outlook-365

The count of my contacts in the outlook web interface (outlook.office.com/people/) is wrong. When I select all contacts (ctrl + a or check the "your contacts" checkbox on top of the list), it says 1584 contacts selected, which is wrong :

- in my windows 10 outlook 365 app, I have 1595 contacts
- when I check properties of the contacts folder, on the synchronization tab, it also says that there are 1595 contacts both locally *and* on the server
- and, weirdest of all, when I export the contacts from the web interface and I check the csv file, there are indeed 1595 contacts

I identified a few of the "missing" (in the web interface) contacts, and even when searching for a specific contact (which is rightly present in the csv file), no contact with that name is found.

The context is that I am switching my usage (and samsung phone syncing) from one account (with associated laptop) to a different office 365 account. The steps I took :

- With the old exchange account, make sure web interface and windows 10 outlook contacts are synced, and both show indeed 1595 contacts
- Export the contacts from the outlook (Office 2013) on the laptop to a .pst file
- Import the contacts from this .pst file to the contacts of the windows 10 outlook (Office 365) of the more recent laptop (and with the new exchange account) (and I still get the same 1595 contacts as explained above)
- Then sync with the outlook web interface, where I only see 1584 contacts ...

And I also noticed that what I see in the web interface, is not exactly what happened on the back-end server (describing in my layman's terms). I understand from the process (and following the syncing results), that on the server there are indeed the 1595 contacts (so the info on the properties tab of my windows 10 outlook is correct) and the csv export also happens from that server database, but something "goes wrong" between the server and what is displayed in the actual web interface.

The only suspicion I have is that it has to do with the creation date of these 11 contacts, because the missing ones are generally the most recently created, and maybe with the way dates are kept in the contact (D/M/Y vs M/D/Y).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have expanded the folder pane to show all contacts.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In the folder pane, the "Your contacts" folder is selected. It is the folder with personal contacts. And then I check the checkbox "Your contacts" (unchecked in your screenshot), and the count displayed on the panel at the right is wrong. It is really something about that web interface not fetching all contacts from the server (where it is correct, as I have the same number of contacts on my synced phone, on my synced laptop, and in the exported csv file.